# Laravel Nova not working with Laravel Spark: Unexpected token P in JSON at position 1213

Tags: laravel, laravel-spark, laravel-nova

After installing Laravel Nova to my Spark application and going to `/nova`, the nova interface showed, but I can't click anything.

Opening the dev console, I see the following errors:

[image: Nova errors in dev console]

Answer (score 4):

In `app/resources/lang/en.json` you'll find 4 instances of `\"`. Changing all those to single quotes fixes the issue.

[image: Nova without issues]

Comment: if I update `/resources/lang/vendor/nova/en.json` for other things like changing "Lens" to "View", the app doesn't pickup the change. Are you seeing your changes to en.json get picked up by Nova?

Comment: Nevermind. If I create an `en.json` at `/resources/lang/en.json` and override only what I need, it works.

Comment: Hey thanks for this integration! I'm discovering Nova and was looking to integrate it with my Spark app, which looks like interesting to have.

If you got any more updates on how you went further, replacing current Spark admin for example or other integration topics, it could be good!

Thanks.